# responsive-nav.js on wordpress menu doesn't work

Tags: html, wordpress, css, menu, responsive-design

I'm using the http://responsive-nav.com/ system in my wordpress theme but I have some bugs with the responsive menu.
With this html code it works (without wordpress menu):

```
    <nav class="nav-collapse">
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

But with the wordpress menu it doesn't:

```
    <nav class="nav-collapse">
      <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Main' )); ?>
    </nav>
```

Do you have an idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,
I replace:

```
    <nav class="nav-collapse">
      <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Main' )); ?>
    </nav>
```

by:

```
    <nav>
      <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Main','container_class' => 'nav-collapse' )); ?>
    </nav>
```

and it works like that.